# Print Elements from Data Frame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {'sport' : ['football', 'hockey', 'baseball', 'basketball', 'nan'], 'league': ['NFL', 'NHL', 'MLB', 'NBA', 'NaN'], 'number': [1,2,3,4,'']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df

def printlinesindf(datafrm):
    print('This is my favrotie sport:', df[0], 'and this is my favorite league: ',df[1], 'and this is my ranking: ', df[0]')
    
printlinesindf(df)
```

This produces an error; I'd like to print each element of the row somehow using the apply function rather than a simple for loop statement. I do not want to include the header (i.e., sport, league, number).

Example expected output for line one `this is my favorite sport: football, this is my favorite league: NFL, this is my ranking: 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future needs, you may want to generate a column with these values and then do the single print:

```python
import pandas as pd

df = {
    'sport' : ['football', 'hockey', 'baseball', 'basketball'], 
    'league': ['NFL', 'NHL', 'MLB', 'NBA'], 
    'number': [1,2,3,4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

def printlinesindf(datafrm):
    datafrm['joined'] = 'This is my favorite sport: ' + datafrm['sport'] + \
        ' and this is my favorite league: ' + datafrm['league'] + \
            ' and this is my ranking: ' + datafrm['number'].astype(str)
    # print one string of all the rows in the dataframe separate with a newline
    print(datafrm['joined'].str.cat(sep='\n')) 

printlinesindf(df)
```

I took into account that you want to generate a single print with all the lines, now if you want a print for each line, there are other approaches such as:

```python
import pandas as pd

df = {
    'sport' : ['football', 'hockey', 'baseball', 'basketball'], 
    'league': ['NFL', 'NHL', 'MLB', 'NBA'], 
    'number': [1,2,3,4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

def printlinesindf(datafrm):
    datafrm['joined'] = 'This is my favorite sport: ' + datafrm['sport'] + \
        ' and this is my favorite league: ' + datafrm['league'] + \
            ' and this is my ranking: ' + datafrm['number'].astype(str)
    # print each row of the dataframe 'joined' column
    for a in datafrm['joined']:
        print(a)

printlinesindf(df)
```

Added doubt (`I also updated the code to show...`) after editing the original question:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {
    'sport' : ['football', 'hockey', 'baseball', 'basketball'], 
    'league': ['NFL', 'NHL', 'MLB', 'NBA'], 
    'number': [1,2,3,'']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
# remove lines with empty values
df = df[df['number'] != '']
```

Comment: Thank you!  I also updated the code to show that there is an 'nan' (string) within the data frame. How would I remove the rows with the 'nan' string? @Digital Farmer

Comment: @HelpMeCode I put an additional point in my answer, but please, next time create new questions for additional questions, because it is not recommended to edit the data of the original question after there are already answers that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use apply you can do something like this:

```
def printlinesindf(row):
    print('This is my favrotie sport:', row[0], 'and this is my favorite league: ',row[1], 'and this is my ranking: ', row[2])
    
df.apply(lambda row: printlinesindf(row), axis=1)
```

However, this is not faster than a for loop.

Comment: Thanks!  Why is it correct to put ```row``` instead of indexing the ```df``` itself? @Stefan

Comment: You can do that too, but that would defeat the purpose of ```df.apply``` as it's meant to  apply a helper function, so you might as well just loop. Besides, this way you avoid accessing global variables in your function @HelpMeCode

Comment: Does it really matter what the ```row``` variable is called in the function?  I just replaced it with ```file``` and it also seemed to work.  Thoughts? @Stefan

Comment: You can name it anything you want. I chose row as that is what it is, a row by row operation. :) @HelpMeCode

Comment: Thanks!  Also have a question on the function.  If I run ```printlines(file)```, I will get an error message; however, it doesn't produce an error message with the ```df.apply``` function.  Why is this the case?  Shouldn't it theoretically work either way? @Stefan

Comment: I also updated the code to show that there's an 'nan' (string) in there.  How would I remove the rows with the 'nan' string? @Stefan